# Size of Rust Hashmap

Tags: rust, hashmap, out-of-memory, large-files

My Rust program is consuming too much memory, causing the Linux Out-Of-Memory Killer to be invoked.

The program takes a file as input and performs multiple operations, including finding duplicated (group of) lines. Hashmaps are used to perform these operations, but their size becomes significant if the file is very large.

What is the recommended way to handle this issue ? How can I dynamically get the size of a hashmap in Rust ? Is there a simple solution to know the maximum size not to exceed ?

```
pub struct Key {
    pub code: String,
    pub num: String,
    pub ref: String,
    pub date: String,
}

pub struct Data {
    pub d: FixedI64<U16>,
    pub c: FixedI64<U16>,
}


    ...

    let mut map: HashMap<Key, Data> = HashMap::new();

    for (i, line) in reader.lines().skip(1).enumerate() {

        let line = line.unwrap_or_default();
        insert_in_hashmap(&line, &mut map);
        
    }

    ...
```

Comment: What are you storing inside your `HashMap`s? In particular, are you storing `String`s (which results in multiple copies of the data in RAM) or `&str`s (which are simply pointers to shared data)?

Comment: Welcome to [SO] ... I am one of the folks that marked this question to be closed because your question does not have enough information (e.g. type of data, code you are using to construct the hashmaps etc.). Please include an [mcve] that we can use as an example to help with. Please edit the question to add that information, if you have an example data file, may be you can share it on github (redact any sensitive information). I'll vote to reopen it :)

Comment: I can't share files, but I added the code logic and data structure.

Comment: Can you give simple stats? like how many lines? or how big the dataset is?

Comment: Yes. The file size is 35 GB and there are about 160 million lines. There is approximately 1 new entry in hashmap for every 10-15 lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can check how many elements `HashMap` has allocated with method [`capacity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.capacity) and you can try reserving more memory with [`try_reserve`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.try_reserve). However likely this is not a problem, because you probably are storing `String`s in this `HashMap`, and they are only 3 words in size. You should therefore track how much memory this `String`s are using, which will be much more difficult.

There is no universal solution for handling OOM errors. If your files are too big to fit in the memory you can't really do anything about it. Unfortunately fallible allocations in rust are still work in progress, so there are not many options for trying to reserve memory (although most standard collections have `try_reserve` methods).